# What are the best strength routines for runners?

Tags: running, strength-training, long-distance-running, hamstring, functional-strength

I am moving to a house and finally have the space to build a home gym. I run 10-15km daily and would like to use the gym for strength training, specifically for my hip flexors, quads and hamstrings for running, though upper body work is also desired.

Any suggestions on equipment and routines for the above?

Comment: This is pretty broad and generic, what are you looking to gain from the weights? What are your goals?